# xgBoost [Rank:Pairwise]: Cross Validation doesn't work as expected (it launches a runtime error)

Tags: python, machine-learning, ranking, cross-validation, xgboost

- Operating System: MacOSX 10.12.4
- Compiler: gcc5
- Package used (python/R/jvm/C++): Python
- 'xgboost' version used: 0.6 (downloaded yesterday from 'pip install')
- Python version = 2.7.13

### Steps to reproduce

I would like to apply pairwise ranking model, as the one in this library (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost).

After setting up the DMatrix and using the set_group() method (I've passed to this method a numpy.array data structure), I've encountered a problem while CrossValidation.
Here is my Python source code:

```
xgdmat = xgb.DMatrix(X_training, y_training) # Create our DMatrix to make XGBoost more efficient
xgdmat.set_group(group=groups_query_id) # Set the query_id values to DMatrix data structure

model_parameters = {'objective': 'rank:pairwise', 'seed': 0, 'booster' : ['gbtree', 'gblinear, dart'],
'eta': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], 'gamma' : [0, 1],
'subsample': [0.5, 0.75, 0.9],
'max_depth': [3, 5], 'min_child_weight': 1, 'max_delta_step' : 0,
'colsample_bytree': [0.5, 0.75, 0.9], 'colsample_bylevel' : [0.5, 0.75, 0.9],
'lambda' : 1, 'alpha' : 0, 'tree_method' : ['auto', 'exact', 'approx', 'hist']}

cv_xgb = xgb.cv(params=model_parameters, dtrain=xgdmat, num_boost_round=1000, nfold=10, metrics=['auc', 'ndcg', 'map'], early_stopping_rounds=100) #THE PROBLEM OCCURS HERE!!!

print cv_xgb.tail(5)

final_gb = xgb.train(model_parameters, xgdmat, num_boost_round=500)
```

When I launch this program, I find this kind of problem:
**"Check failed: (src.info.group_ptr.size()) == (0) slice does not support group structure"**

```
 [15:43:58] dmlc-core/include/dmlc/logging.h:235: [15:43:58] src/c_api/c_api.cc:342: Check failed: (src.info.group_ptr.size()) == (0) slice does not support group structure
```

[15:43:58] dmlc-core/include/dmlc/logging.h:235: [15:43:58] src/c_api/c_api.cc:342: Check failed: (src.info.group_ptr.size()) == (0) slice does not support group structure
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/edoardo/PycharmProjects/MasterThesisProject/extra/Prova.py", line 225, in metodo3() File "/Users/edoardo/PycharmProjects/MasterThesisProject/extra/Prova.py", line 164, in metodo3 metrics=['auc, ''ndcg', 'map'], early_stopping_rounds=100) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.py", line 371, in cv cvfolds = mknfold(dtrain, nfold, params, seed, metrics, fpreproc, stratified, folds) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.py", line 248, in mknfold dtrain = dall.slice(np.concatenate([idset[i] for i in range(nfold) if k != i])) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 531, in slice ctypes.byref(res.handle))) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 127, in _check_call raise XGBoostError(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()) xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [15:43:58] src/c_api/c_api.cc:342: Check failed: (src.info.group_ptr.size()) == (0) slice does not support group structure

### What have you tried?

1. I've tried to pass a numpy.array as input for set_group() method
2. I've tried to pass a list as input for set_group() method

Any tips or workaround for resolving this problem? I know that many people have the same problem as mine, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me.
According to my error message, maybe it has something to do with xgb.cv'nfold fun.

Basically with group information,a stratified nfold should take place, but how to do a stratified nfold? with labels or group_info? which one make's more sence?Maybe it's not clear.

Try to directly use sklearn's Stratified K-Folds instead. Or just use different groups. Some group for train, Some group for test.